# can't get a text from EditText

Tags: java, android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()'

Here is my XML :

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/linkvideo"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:background="@drawable/et_back"
   android:hint="@string/paste"
   android:padding="15dp"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:textColorHint="@color/grey"
   android:textSize="15sp"
   android:inputType="text"/>
```

Here is my java :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        EditText inputurl;
        String newLink;
        TextView down_btn ,show;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            inputurl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.linkvideo);
            down_btn=findViewById(R.id.down_btn);
            show=findViewById(R.id.show);
    
            down_btn.setOnClickListener(this::videoDownload);
    
    
        }
        public void videoDownload(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicking ....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String ans=inputurl.getText().toString();
            show.setText(ans);
        }
    
    }
```

I can't get a text please tell me what's wrong with this Code

Comment: `EditText != TextView`

Comment: please show the entire `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: Use `inputurl.getEditableText.toSring()`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display text, please heed  Darkman's advice i.e. use TextView.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

**Please don't name your TextView as *btn* and *show* as they are very misleading.**

I'm assuming that you want to:

- click down_btn TextView and trigger method videoDownload
- videoDownload will display a toast message then...
- Text typed in EditText to show on show TextView.

I tried your code on emulator and it's working. The text from EditText is displayed in the "show" Textview.

Please check your other xml attributes.

Here is what I'm using. I replaced some of the attributes and apply no design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/linkvideo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:hint="Some hint"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/down_btn"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/down_btn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="CLICK HERE"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linkvideo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/show"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TextView for text in EditText to display when click: CLICK HERE "
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/down_btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        />





</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```